# More efficient ways of listing matchings of possible rolls of 10 dice by max matching

Tags: combinatorics

The question is inspired by a dice game named 'Tenzi'. You roll 10 dice and record the size of the largest matching (the face-value is irrelevant). Exhaustively, listing all combinations of matchings would look like this:

```
pairs = {
    {{2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}},
    {{3, 3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 
    3, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}},
    {{4, 4, 2}, {4, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 2, 2, 2}, {4,
     3, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}},
    {{5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {5, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {5, 2, 2, 1}, {5, 3, 1, 
    1}, {5, 3, 2}, {5, 4, 1}, {5, 5}},
    {{6, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {6, 2, 1, 1}, {6, 2, 2}, {6, 3, 1}, {6, 4}},
    {{7, 1, 1, 1}, {7, 2, 1}, {7, 3}},
    {{8, 1, 1}, {8, 2}},
    {{9, 1}},
    {{10}}
}
```

e.g., looking at the first line, `{2,2,2,2,2}` corresponds to five pairs and `{2,2,2,2,1,1}` corresponds to four pairs and two singles. These are the only possible matchings with a maximum of 2 (since a die only has 6 sides), and so it is in its own nested list.

I wrote the following code that comes up with an equivalent list, but it is very inefficient due to using `Tuples[Range[10],n]`.

```
pairs = Table[Select[Flatten[Table[Select[DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Tuples[Range[10], n]], 
    Total[#] == 10 &], {n, 1, 6}], 1], Max[#] == i &], {i, 2, 10}];
```

Any ideas on how to make this more efficient so I can generalize to more than 10 dice?

Comment: Have you seen [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html)? E.g. `GatherBy[#, First] &@Select[IntegerPartitions[10], Length@# < 7 &]`.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks. I was not aware of `GatherBy[]` nor `IntegerPartitions[]`.

Comment: I'm curious - what are you going to do with the results, that is, is this an x y problem, and you're after some count of possibilities, or probabilities of same, or are you actually just after the total enumeration? If the former, much more efficient ways to do those...

Comment: I'm creating a probability distribution of the sizes of the maximum matchings, i.e., the result of any play of Tenzi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`IntegerPartitions[n, k]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html) will give all possible ways to sum positive integers to `n` using at most `k` numbers. Then you can `GatherBy` the `First` element to form sublists (`Reverse` to have them in ascending order):

```
pairs = Reverse @ GatherBy[#, First] & @ IntegerPartitions[10, 6]

(* Output: {{{2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}}, {{3, 3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2, 
   2}, {3, 3, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 2,
    1, 1, 1}}, {{4, 4, 2}, {4, 4, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 3}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 
   3, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 2, 2}, {4, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
   1}}, {{5, 5}, {5, 4, 1}, {5, 3, 2}, {5, 3, 1, 1}, {5, 2, 2, 1}, {5,
    2, 1, 1, 1}, {5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, {{6, 4}, {6, 3, 1}, {6, 2, 
   2}, {6, 2, 1, 1}, {6, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, {{7, 3}, {7, 2, 1}, {7, 1, 1, 
   1}}, {{8, 2}, {8, 1, 1}}, {{9, 1}}, {{10}}} *)
```

This works well up to at least `n = 100`. For `n = 150` I have to wait a few seconds - unless I want to have the output displayed, which takes most of the time. I got bored waiting for `n = 200` to display (there are $4,775,383$ partitions), but just calculating it takes only a moment. For higher `n` it may not be too efficient.

Comment: Use the second argument for `IntegerPartitions`: `IntegerPartitions[10, 6]` instead of `Select[IntegerPartitions[10], Length @ # < 7 &]`. (It's much faster: It does the $n=100$ case in less than a second.)

Comment: @march Thanks; I usually throw the first version of a working code and then improve the details once it's _published_.

Comment: Yes, this is a lot faster. For n=100 there are more than 190 million partitions so limiting the partition to 6 parts saves a lot of time.